# JQuery Ajax WebMethod return an object

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, ajax, webmethod

I have a web Method in my C# that is called via Jquery ajax method. The web method should return an object back to the Jquery which will be used to populate.

I have tried returning a JsonResult object, the actual object and nothing seems to work! I'm not using MVC (Unfortunately). Is there a way that I can return an object from my web method which can be used by my AJAX method?

here is the link for my JQuery AJAX method

http://pastebin.com/tRSaY5rG

http://pastebin.com/WajXyPMM

Thanks!!

Comment: please post your full source code of asmx too

Comment: oh ok. sorry. Change Error in your $.ajax call to error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
        alert(ajaxOptions);
    } and check what error you are getting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have used JQuery to get results from a database and populate a UL on a page with the items. Is this what you were looking for?

Javascript

```
        //Set up Approve Requests Page
        $("#approveRequests").bind('pageAnimationEnd', function () { getRequestList(); return false; });

        //Gets the list of requests
        function getRequestList() {
            // call server-side webmethod using jQuery
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "Index.aspx/GetOrdersForApproving",
                data: "{ }", // send an empty object for calls with no parameters
                dataType: "json",
                success: displayRequests,
                failure: reportError
            });
        }

        //displays the requests in the ul
        function displayRequests(result) {
            // ASP.NET encapsulates JSON responses in a property "d"
            if (result.hasOwnProperty("d")) { result = result.d; }
            // iterate through player list and add info to the markup
            var ul = $("#requestsForApproval");
            for (i = 0; i " + result[i].Supplier + "," + result[i].Description + "," + result[i].Value + "");
                var li = $(""
            + "" + result[i].OrderID + " - " + result[i].Supplier + ""
        + ""
        + ""
            + result[i].Description
        + ""
        + " "
            + ""
                + ""
                    + ""
                         + "Quant: " + result[i].Quantity
                    + ""
                    + ""
                        + "Price: " + result[i].UnitPrice
                    + ""
                    + ""
                        + "Total: " + result[i].Value
                    + ""
                + ""
            + ""
        + ""
          + " "
            + "Approve"
            + "Reject"
        + ""
        + ""
        + "");
                ul.append(li);
            }
```

ASPX

```
        /// 
        /// Gets a list of Request Lines
        /// 
        /// List of order lines
        [WebMethod]
        public static List GetOrdersForApproving()
        {
            try
            {
                List Lines = new List();
                foreach (Objects.Database.OrderLine oOrderLine in Objects.Database.OrderLine.GetLinesWaitingFor(StaticStore.CurrentUser.UserID, int.MinValue))
                {
                    Lines.Add(new iOrderLine(oOrderLine));
                }

                return Lines;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

The bit that code me struggling to get this working was:

```
if (result.hasOwnProperty("d")) { result = result.d; }
```